# Samba4 server visible with IP on the network

Tags: windows, active-directory, bind, samba, samba4

I have a Samba4 AD setup. I cannot understand why the server is visible on the net only by its IP address and not by hostname.

[image: screenshot of network browsing]

The configuration looks ok to me, the same as we have in other places where it's working as expected.

If I try accessing `\\SERVER7` works fine.

```
[global]
    server services = s3fs, rpc, nbt, wrepl, ldap, cldap, kdc, drepl, winbindd, ntp_signd, kcc, dnsupdate
    realm = domain.lan
    ldap server require strong auth = no
    netbios name = SERVER7
    workgroup = DOMAIN
    server role = active directory domain controller
    log level = 5
    idmap_ldb:use rfc2307 = yes
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    ea support = yes
[users]
    path = /home/users/
    read only = no
[profiles]
    comment = Users profiles
    path = /home/profiles
    read only = no
    browsable = no
```

Could it be a reverse dns issue? This is the BIND config for the 10.0.0 zone:

```
$TTL    86400
@       IN      SOA     samba.domain.lan samba.domain.lan (
                        1997022705
                        28800
                        14400
                        3600000
                        86400 )
              NS      samba.server7.
              NS      samba.domain.lan.
              NS      server01.domain.com.
              NS      mailing.domain.com.
;              IN      NS      10.0.0.7
7                   PTR     samba.domain.lan.
7                   PTR     wpad.domain.com.
2                   PTR     server02.domain.com.
14                  PTR     mailing.domain.com.
7.0.0.10.in-addr.arpa.  IN      PTR     server7.
```

Sample `nslookup` and `ipconfig` from a client:

```
C:\Users\administrator.DOMAIN>nslookup server7.domain.lan
Server:  samba.domain.lan
Address:  10.0.0.7

Nome:    server7.domain.lan
Addresses:  10.0.0.7
          192.168.0.7

C:\Users\administrator.DOMAIN>nslookup 10.0.0.7
Server:  server7
Address:  10.0.0.7

Nome:    server7
Address:  10.0.0.7

C:\Users\administrator.DOMAIN>ipconfig /all

Configurazione IP di Windows

   Nome host . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : VM01W7
   Suffisso DNS primario . . . . . . . . : domain.lan
   Tipo nodo . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Ibrido
   Routing IP abilitato. . . . . . . . . : No
   Proxy WINS abilitato . . . . . . . .  : No
   Elenco di ricerca suffissi DNS. . . . : domain.lan

Scheda Ethernet Connessione alla rete locale (LAN):

   Suffisso DNS specifico per connessione:
   Descrizione . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Connessione di rete Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT
   Indirizzo fisico. . . . . . . . . . . : 00-C1-44-71-14-CD
   DHCP abilitato. . . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Configurazione automatica abilitata   : Sì
   Indirizzo IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.12(Preferenziale)
   Subnet mask . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Gateway predefinito . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.250
   Server DNS . . . . . . . . . . . . .  : 10.0.0.7
   Server WINS primario . . . . . . . .  : 10.0.0.7
   NetBIOS su TCP/IP . . . . . . . . . . : Attivato
```

Samba 4.3.11 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: I think the problems is likely to be the PTR record. `nslookup 10.0.0.7` randomly returns one of the three configured hosts (samba, server7 and wpad), maybe Windows is *confused* by this ambiguity...?

Comment: Even after *fixing* PTR (removed the additional entries, now it replies with just one host) in Windows it's still visible as IP instead of hostsname

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though your client is not configured to use the Samba 4 AD DC as its DNS provider.

Please ensure that the client is pointed as the AD DC for DNS and post the results of your nslookup for `server7.domain.lan`

Comment: Added `ifconfig` and `nslookup` output